# HandsOnTable sheetName Does not exists in type DetailedSettings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, handsontable

Getting this error when I use `sheetName` in formulas along with `engine : HyperFormula` from official documentation.

> ‘sheetName’ does not exist in type ‘DetailedSettings’

This is how I am setting `<HotTable />` component.

```
<HotTable
// Other config

data={data[key as keyof typeof data]}
formulas={{
      engine: hyperformulaInstance,
      sheetName: "MySheet", /* Type '{ engine: HyperFormula; sheetName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedSettings'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'sheetName'does not exist in type 'DetailedSettings'. */
}}

// Other config
licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation" // for non-commercial use only
/>
```

formulas is expecting DetailedSettings which does not contain `sheetName` property.

Removing `sheetName:'MySheet'` works and runs the app without error.

Comment: any help? its urgent... why plugin is not working for such a basic thing.

Comment: Hi. This issue has been raised on Handsontable forum and reported as a bug on the Github issue board at https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/10023

Answer (score 0):

As for now 14 OCT, 2022. This is a bug in only `React+Typescript` projects.
https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/10023

A hack is to cast object as any.

```
   formulas={
                {
                  engine: hyperformulaInstance,
                  sheetName: "Sheet1",
                } as any
              }
```